# How to add Nametags to a Multi-user WebVR in A-frame

Tags: aframe, webvr

I'm building a multi-user experience in A-frame, I'm very new to coding and A-frame, so I started the project remixing the networked audio (https://glitch.com/~networked-aframe-audio) and using it as base to build the environment. I wanted to add nametags to each user as well, so seeing that this (https://glitch.com/~naf-nametags) has most of the same code than the audio project, I tried taking the avatar template and script parts missing and pasting it in my code. It doesn't work, but even if I remix the naf-nametags project and add a simple cube to the scene, it stops working. I tried for a couple days to understand why, by I don't seem to find the answer.
Sorry if it's the stupidest question ever, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Dver, can you please add a code example of what you are trying to do, and what you have done so far? Otherwise the community won't be able to help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for replying. Here's the code I'm working with: https://glitch.com/~indigo-roomy-supermarket
I've managed to mix both in one, using the naf nametags as a base. The problem I'm facing now is that that version of a-frame is very unstable on mobile phones (image shaking violently). I know that the solution is updating to the latest a-frame, but when I update to 1.0.4 (or anything above 0.8.2 for that matter), the avatars don't update their position anymore. I don't know if that would need a different thread but...if you have any idea how to solve this it would be amazing!